# Проблема с json в while

Tags: php, json, while

В цикле я собираю файлы. Мне нужно вернуть это в JSON в таком формате:

```
{"1":"d.txt","2":"dj.txt"}
```

Но меня выходит так:

```
{"1":"d.txt"}{"2":"dj.txt"}
```

Вот код:

```
<?
$files = array_diff(scandir("plug/lol/"), ['.','..']);
$lole = [
"count" => count($files)
];
//echo json_encode($lole);
foreach($files as $key=>$lol){
    $result = [
    $key-1=> $lol
    ];
    echo json_encode($result);
}
?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Посмотрите на свой код

```
foreach($files as $key=>$lol){
    $result = [
        $key-1=> $lol
    ];
    echo json_encode($result);
}
```

на каждой итерации цикла вы заново определяете массив, и сразу же выводите результат. Вам же надо на итерации добавлять элемент, а вывести все в конце

```
foreach($files as $key=>$lol){
    $result[$key-1] = $lol;
}
echo json_encode($result);
```

Comment: но у меня выводиться только последний элемент массива

Comment: https://pastebin.com/xVZSJm8s

Answer (score 1):

Поможет вам `array_merge()`

```
<?
$files = array_diff(scandir("plug/lol/"), ['.','..']);
$array = [];
$lole = [
"count" => count($files)
];
//echo json_encode($lole);
foreach($files as $key=>$lol){
    $result = [
        $key-1=> $lol
    ];
    $array = array_merge($array, $result);
}
echo json_encode($array);
?>
```